# Cocos2d Animation inside a Sprite Object

Tags: javascript, animation, cocos2d-js

In a Cocos2d-x V 3.81 project, I am trying to animate a sprite inside an object which extends Sprite, but it does not seem to do anything. Is it even possible to have an animated sprite inside such a node, or does it have to extend Layer to have animation?

```
var Player = cc.Sprite.extend ({
ctor: function () {

    this._super(res.Player_png);

    this.UP = false;
    this.DOWN = false;
    this.LEFT = false;
    this.RIGHT = false;
    this.ACTION = false;

    this.speed = 5;

    cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrame(res.Player_Left_plist);

    var leftFrames = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var str = "Left" + i + ".png";
        var frame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str);
        leftFrames.push(frame);
    }

    this.leftAnim = new cc.Animation(leftFrames, 0.3);
    this.runLeft = new cc.repeatForever(new cc.Animate(this.leftAnim));

    this.state = "nothing";
    this.nothing = "nothing";

    this.scheduleUpdate();

    cc.eventManager.addListener (
        cc.EventListener.create ({
            event: cc.EventListener.KEYBOARD ,
            onKeyPressed: function(key, event)
            {
                if(key == 87) this.UP = true;
                else if(key == 65) this.LEFT = true;
                else if(key == 83) this.DOWN = true;
                else if(key == 68) this.RIGHT = true;
                else if (key == 69 || key == 32) this.ACTION = true;
            }.bind(this),
            onKeyReleased: function(key, event)
            {

                if(key == 87) this.UP = false;
                else if(key == 65) this.LEFT = false;
                else if(key == 83) this.DOWN = false;
                else if(key == 68) this.RIGHT = false;
                else if (key == 69 || key == 32) this.ACTION = false;
            }.bind(this)
        }),this);

    return true;
},

update:function(dt) {
    if(this.UP)
    {
        this.y += this.speed;
        this.runAction(this.runLeft);
    }
    else if(this.DOWN)
    {
        this.y -= this.speed;
    }
    if(this.LEFT)
    {
        this.x -= this.speed;
        this.runAction(this.runLeft);
    }
    else if(this.RIGHT)
    {
        this.x += this.speed;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: you should mark as correct the answer of user1615873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pluralization was largely the problem.

For those curious, here is the block of functional code:

You are correct. Thank you very much. For those interested, this is the block of functional code:

```
    cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.playerRun_plist);
    var i,f;
    var frames=[];
    for (i=1; i <= 4; i++) {
        f=cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame("playerRun"+i+".png");
        frames.push(f);
    }
    var playerRunAnim = new cc.Animation(frames, 0.1);
    this.playerAction = new cc.RepeatForever(new cc.Animate(playerRunAnim));

    this.runAction(this.playerAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this line:

```
cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrame(res.Player_Left_plist);
```

It should read

```
cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.Player_Left_plist);
```

where SpriteFrames is plural. The method without an 's' on the end is used to load a single cc.SpriteFrame object into the cache, after you've created that SpriteFrame manually.  the method WITH an 's' on the end is the one that takes a URL for a plist to load a whole spritesheet at once.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.8/symbols/cc.spriteFrameCache.html

Answer (score 0):

This code works for you outside the sprite class? For example in a regular sprite?

I think this is wrong but I have not tested it:

this.leftAnim = new cc.Animation(leftFrames, 0.3);
this.runLeft = new cc.repeatForever(new cc.Animate(this.leftAnim));

With your code what I'd do:

```
var leftAnim = new cc.Animation();
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var str = "Left" + i + ".png";
        var frame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str);
        leftAnim.addSpriteFrame(frame);
    }
leftAnim.setDelayPerUnit(0.08);
this.runAction(cc.animate(leftAnim)); //or this.runAction(cc.animate(leftAnim).repeatForever());
```

Hope it helps